# Column in query should be selected according to value from another column

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have table1 with following data:

*table1*

```
id| coffee_sender | coffee_receiver | received_bag_size | sent_bag_size| price |
21  tux              -1                  m                 -1            45 
22  alsa            -1                  -1                 xl            36
23  -1               tux                 l                 -1            51
```

And I use the following query:

```
select t1.*
from (
select t.price, t.id
from table1 t 
where coffee_sender in (tux, alsa) 
or coffee_receiver in (tux, alsa)
and received_bag_size in (m, xl)
or sent_bag_size in (m, xl)) t1
```

What i want is to only fetch the rows that have coffee_sender/coffee_receiver AND sent_bag_size/received_bag_size filled with a value (rows that match the following conditions):

```
coffee_sender = tux, sent_bag_size= xl
```

OR

```
coffee_receiver = tux, received_bag_size= m
```

OR

```
coffee_sender = tux, sent_bag_size = xl AND coffee_receiver = tux, received_bag_size= m
```

So id = 21 would be excluded from the example table1.

How can i update the above query for this ? Thank you in advance.

Update: to make the question a little more clear:
What i want to see is the actual rows where coffee vendor and size are linked. Each coffee vendor (tux, alsa) has a bag size at a a certain point in time. This will be inserted in the table when shipment is done.

I hope this clarifies what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Select **ONE** DBMS, remove wrong tag. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide 2-3 variants of input criteria and desired outputs for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.price, t.id
from table1 t 
where (coffee_sender = tux and sent_bag_size= xl)
or (coffee_receiver = tux and received_bag_size= m)
or (coffee_sender = tux and sent_bag_size = xl AND coffee_receiver = tux and received_bag_size= m)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I receive dynamic lists of values for each set of 2 columns (coffee_sender/rec and sent/received_bag_size). These lists can vary from 1 to hundreds of values. I don't think this is exactly what i had in mind.

Comment: Please add also some explanation to your query, so that others can use it when it helps

Comment: @acomplisher could you please modify the question and tell us more about list of conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You see in my answer that i excluded all rows that have -1 as their value

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`id` int, `coffee_sender` varchar(4), `coffee_receiver` varchar(3), `received_bag_size` varchar(2), `sent_bag_size` varchar(2), `price` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`id`, `coffee_sender`, `coffee_receiver`, `received_bag_size`, `sent_bag_size`, `price`)
> VALUES
>     (21, 'tux', '-1', 'm', '-1', 45),
>     (22, 'alsa', '-1', '-1', 'xl', 36),
>     (23, '-1', 'tux', 'l', '-1', 51)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id,price
> FROM Table1
> WHERE (`coffee_sender` <> -1 AND `sent_bag_size` <> -1) OR (`coffee_receiver` <> -1 AND `received_bag_size` <> -1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | price
> -: | ----:
> 22 |    36
> 23 |    51
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db71abe94090dfb3dff5c403c1d91b3e)*